# Blender is not rendering in the viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

In the viewport, it doesn’t render (when using cycles because eevee doesn’t look right) on the top left corner it says initializing but it never starts rendering. I have let it sit for more then 15 minutes. I do have a slow computer but not that slow. here is a pic of the viewport:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Your render is paused** .[image]
Click on the top right icon shown in the image to switch it back on.

Don't mind the clipping... (The one in the second circle)

This function is normally used to prevent a view port render from updating even if we make any changes to any thing or try to mave in the viewport.

Comment: wow a click of a button for almost 2 weeks of mental pain. thank you so much (:

Comment: You can select the answer as the correct one if that solved ur problem . Happy that I could help u :)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried altering the resolution and number of light bounces to see if that speeds up rendering to help resolving your issue? 15 minutes does seem like an extremely long time to see something from most computers. Is the item just using a standard colour as well?